# Use Conditional formatting for whole Google Sheet Workbook to search for duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Use Conditional formatting for whole Google Sheet Workbook
Currently I am using the single color CONDITIONAL FORMATTING for two columns in every worksheet that looks at the column and if there is a similar match with the single worksheet within that column it will highlight the column in yellow.

APPLY TO RANGE:
C1:C1000

FORMAT RULES
Format cells if ...
=if(C1<>"",Countif(C:C,left(C1,18)& "*") > 1)

Formatting Style
I selected yellow

And I do exactly the same thing for Column D

Now that I have over 10 worksheets and it is growing week by week I am finding that there are duplicates happening between the sheets, as conditional formatting only works per sheet.

So is there a way for me to do have Google Sheet conditionally format the entire workbook by looking at column C and column D and if there is a match that it highlights it in yellow.

If there is a script or macro that someone can actually code for me (as I don't know how to do it) I would really appreciate.  Alternatively if anyone knows an easy way to do what I need done, I would be most grateful.

As an example here is a workbook to show you what I mean.
In the google workbook, in Sheet labelled "Visual Test Current" this is what I have been able to currently setup as described.  It works perfectly.

In the sheet labelled "Visual Test Sheet 1" it works fine on the individual sheet itself, however it does not look at "Visual Test Current" and if there is a match based on the formula "=if(D1<>"",Countif(D:D,left(D1,18)& "*") > 1)"
AND
=if(E1<>"",Countif(E:E,left(E1,18)& "*") > 1)

It does not format the cell to tell me that there is a duplicate match in a previous sheet.  That is what I am trying to figure out how to do.

How do I get/create a formula that looks at these two columns through every sheet in Google Workbook and if there is a match based on the parameters of Countif it formats the cell to yellow, highlighting to me that there is a duplicate of that cell somewhere in a sheet in Google Workbook.

Here is the link to the shared Test document to help you visual what I am trying to do.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQryGa9Z325XMv1mU5hq0AhaO3uWbzZ7MSxfY7U4EcPS7hGg281wogKJE98IQjriR4cPIXTCatd-Y8d/pubhtml

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the actual spreadsheet, and not just the published version?

Comment: I cannot. It contains private information of our customers that I am unable to share in an open forum. Hence why I created the sample document.

Comment: Of course it should be with not sensitive data, but it would be useful to share a spreadsheet, and not the `pubhtml` version. Can't you share a spreadsheet with sample data?

Comment: My Error lamblichus.  I actually thought the shared google document gave full access to the document.  

Let me try again.  See if this google share link actually gives you access to the document itself that I have cleared all sensitive data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GBvbR85chg_TnScpyxmziTACKUWHWPDqKwiBa4BuEe8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I had to remove the link from the shared Google Sheets as I only realized that the shared document contained the revision history and this of course showed all the sensitive data.  So I made a copy of the cleared document with no history revision.

Use this link for the document.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QCqAD-9GFVlV74e2Erpbr90DYrnYU-LAsR73Hpy6sLw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So, you want to set yellow background in all the cells in all columns C and D where the cell value has a duplicate in that column, right?

Comment: That is correct. Similar to the formula that I am using that only works for each individual sheet.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304), when you share Google files(this is not true for `/pubhtml`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

- Return all sheets via [Spreadsheet.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) and iterate through them.
- For each sheet, create the conditional formatting rule for columns C and D, using [ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder).
- Add the conditional format rules via [Sheet.setConditionalFormatRules](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setconditionalformatrulesrules).

#### Code sample:

```
const EXCLUDED_SHEETS = ["Sheets that won't be updated"];

function updateAllSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(sheet => !EXCLUDED_SHEETS.includes(sheet.getName()));
  const [cFormula, dFormula] = ["C","D"].map(column => sheets.reduce((acc, sheet, i) => {
    const sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    return acc + (i!=0 ? "+" : "") + `Countif(INDIRECT("'${sheetName}'!${column}:${column}"),left(${column}1,18)&\"*\")`;
  }, `=if(${column}1<>\"\",`) + "> 1)");
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const cRange = sheet.getRange("C1:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
    const cRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied(cFormula)
    .setBackground("yellow")
    .setRanges([cRange])
    .build();
    const dRange = sheet.getRange("D1:D" + sheet.getLastRow());
    const dRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied(dFormula)
    .setBackground("yellow")
    .setRanges([dRange])
    .build();
    sheet.setConditionalFormatRules([cRule,dRule]);
  });
}
```

#### Execute automatically:

If you want to execute this automatically, you should use a trigger. Here, I see two main options:

1. [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger. With this trigger, your function will execute every time a user edits the spreadsheet. To have this trigger, just rename your function `updateAllSheets` to `onEdit`.
2. [Time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). This kind of trigger would execute periodically (for example, every hour). In contrast with `onEdit`, to use this trigger you have to install it first. To install this, either follow [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) or execute a function like this once (the example below refers to a trigger that executes hourly, check [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) to see all the alternatives at your disposal):

```
function createTimeDrivenTrigger() {
  // Trigger every 1 hour.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('updateAllSheets')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(1)
      .create();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Will this work as I add new sheets into the workbook?

Also I noticed that you have the column C, D, however does not include Column E. Is this by purpose, or a mistake?

Comment: One additional question. Do I just copy the code and paste it in Apps Script or do I have to do anything extra as per the solution bullet points?

Comment: @StevieB `Will this work as I add new sheets into the workbook?` Any existing sheet not included in `EXCLUDED_SHEETS` at the moment the function is executed will be handled. After adding new sheets, you should execute this function again to add the rules to the new sheets. `does not include Column E. Is this by purpose, or a mistake?` As far as I can see, you only mentioned columns C and D in your question, no column E. In any case, you can easily modify this script to include column E.

Comment: @StevieB `Do I just copy the code and paste it in Apps Script or do I have to do anything extra as per the solution bullet points` Just paste the code to your script editor, modify the `EXCLUDED_SHEETS` according to your needs, and execute the function. For the future, I'd strongly suggest taking a look at some Apps Script guides.

Comment: @StevieB If you want to automatically apply the formatting rules to new sheets, I'd suggest using a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

Comment: You will notice that in my actual post I had written the following showing Column E as well. "=if(D1<>"",Countif(D:D,left(D1,18)& "") > 1)" AND =if(E1<>"",Countif(E:E,left(E1,18)& "") > 1)

I think I know how to add column E to the formula.  Thank you for your assistance though.

I am not sure what you mean by "execute the function again".  does it not run on its own?  And how do I execute the function?

This is all new to me.

with regards to time-driver trigger, how do I that?

Comment: Do I remove the conditional formatting from each sheet or do I still leave them there?

Comment: @StevieB `does it not run on its own? And how do I execute the function?` No, it doesn't run on its own. You can execute it by selecting the function name on the dropdown on top of the coding area and then click `Run`.

Comment: @StevieB Regarding the time-driven trigger, follow these steps to install it https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually. You can choose which type of trigger you want (whether it's time-driven, what frequency it will execute, etc.). It's pretty straightforward. Also, there's no need to remove conditional formatting, they are reset every time the function executes.

Comment: Once again thank you. @lamblichus. Is there a way to have the script run automatically?

Comment: Hi @StevieB that's where triggers come into the scene. I updated my answer to explain this.

Comment: Hi @lamblichus, I come with bad news.  It is not working.  I have done everything as instructed and tested it by typing in a duplicate from another sheet in the google document and it did not mark it as yellow.

What do I do now?

Comment: Hi @StevieB `tested it by typing in a duplicate from another sheet in the google document` I don't understand what you are saying here, but the script itself should work (I tested it before). Possibly you didn't change it to a trigger or didn't execute? Consider posting a new question in order to tackle this more comfortably.

Comment: I have a lot of troubles with the triggers.    This what I now keep getting as emails. 

The script is used by the document Flyer Handout (Flood the Market Campaign Drops & Delivery).

Summary:

Error Message Count
Script function not found: updateAllSheets 6
Start Function Error Message Trigger End
5/24/22 2:21:17 AM EDT updateAllSheets Script function not found: updateAllSheets edit 5/24/22 2:21:18 AM EDT
5/24/22 2:22:33 AM EDT updateAllSheets Script function not found: updateAllSheets edit 5/24/22 2:22:33 AM EDT


Google Apps Script

Comment: @StevieB The error you are getting means there's no function called `updateAllSheets` in your script. Since the trigger is supposed to execute a function with that name, it fails. Consider editing your function `createTimeDrivenTrigger` to fire an existing function.

Comment: Can't your code work automatically without a trigger @lamblichus.  I am not sure your code is actually working for me?

Comment: @StevieB Triggers are the way for scripts to run automatically. Either install this or execute the function manually, from the editor.

Comment: @lamblichus, I have run the function manually however it does not highlight the cells in each specific sheet yellow if there is a duplicate or match.

Comment: @StevieB A "duplicate or match" of what? Of sheet names? If that's the case, well this is expected since those names would be explicitly excluded as part of the `EXCLUDED_SHEETS` array.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @lamblichus.  I am referring to the duplicate match of the contents in the respective cells of column C, D and E as per the formula that I wrote which work on individual sheets (see the main question), but does not look at all the sheets in the Google Workbook.  For instance if I have the words Pizza Shop in cell C8 of the worksheet "Stores" and in worksheet "July" in Column C87 I have the same words of Pizza Shop, it should highlight both cells in Yellow.  Hope you can help as the current formula does not do this.

Comment: @StevieB I didn't notice the detail that you wanted to find duplicates across multiple sheets before. I have updated the script from my answer accordingly, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Iamblichus.  The new code words as I needed.  Should I remove my individual sheet conditional formatting formula or where there duplication of results here?

Comment: On another issue, I have found the code works, however is there a way for it to check for duplication from the end of the word and backwards, in that it checks the last 10 letters of each cell and if they are the same it highlights it? @Iamblichus

Comment: @StevieB I think the older conditional formatting would not detect any additional duplicate so it would not affect the resulting highlighting, but it would be sensible to remove it. Regarding `is there a way for it to check for duplication from the end of the word and backwards, in that it checks the last 10 letters of each cell`, just replace `left(${column}1,18)` with `right(${column}1,10)`

Comment: Hi  @Iamblichus once again, the issue I am finding now is that it is finding duplicates that are not actual exact duplicates and may have a few characters different.  How can I amend the coding, so that it searches for the first 10 characters and if the first 10 characters are the same or the last 10 characters are the same, then it highlights, however if there is a single difference, it does not highlight it at all.

Comment: @StevieB I'd suggest you to post a new question for this, since the original issue was already solved. About `the issue I am finding now is that it is finding duplicates that are not actual exact duplicates and may have a few characters different`, it's to be expecting, since you are only checking a certain amount of characters, and not the full word.

Comment: Thanks @lamblichus for the suggestions.  I created a new question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73589719/finding-duplicates-that-are-not-actual-exact-duplicates-and-may-have-a-few-chara