# finding duplicates that are not actual exact duplicates and may have a few characters different

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a previous that was resolved for me at [Use Conditional formatting for whole Google Sheet Workbook to search for duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72209473/use-conditional-formatting-for-whole-google-sheet-workbook-to-search-for-duplica/72257093?noredirect=1#comment129932532_72257093)

I have found that it doesn't actually search for exact duplicates or duplicates where only the last three letters may be different.

I was trying to find a way where the it searches for the first 10 characters and if the first 10 characters are the same or the last 10 characters are the same, then it highlights, however, if there is a single difference, it does not highlight it at all.

The following script is  written by SO user [Iamblicus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10612011/iamblichus) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72257093). If anyone can change this code

```
const EXCLUDED_SHEETS = ["Sheets that won't be updated"];

function updateAllSheets() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(sheet => !EXCLUDED_SHEETS.includes(sheet.getName()));
  const [cFormula, dFormula] = ["C","D"].map(column => sheets.reduce((acc, sheet, i) => {
    const sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    return acc + (i!=0 ? "+" : "") + `Countif(INDIRECT("'${sheetName}'!${column}:${column}"),left(${column}1,18)&\"*\")`;
  }, `=if(${column}1<>\"\",`) + "> 1)");
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    const cRange = sheet.getRange("C1:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
    const cRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied(cFormula)
    .setBackground("yellow")
    .setRanges([cRange])
    .build();
    const dRange = sheet.getRange("D1:D" + sheet.getLastRow());
    const dRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied(dFormula)
    .setBackground("yellow")
    .setRanges([dRange])
    .build();
    sheet.setConditionalFormatRules([cRule,dRule]);
  });
}
```

so that it is search for exact finds, that would be great.

Also I was hoping for an extra line where I can it will exclude specific worksheets.  I am happy to be add the name of the specific worksheets in the code itself, as this can change from time to to time.

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: I did create a link to the original code and have not plagiarised as I stated that I requested someone to change the code from that link and I told lamblicious who made the original code the of the new link as it was he/she that told me to make a new question regarding the original code. Sometimes we should make an assumption as was done here.

Comment: As written in the [referencing help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), `make sure you do **all** of the following:

    Provide a link to the original page or answer
    Quote only the relevant portion
    Provide the name of the original author`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible to do with conditional formatting. Probably it would be more efficient if you're changing the cells constantly.

Just in case, here is the static pure script solution:

```
const EXCLUDED_SHEETS = ['Sheets that won\'t be updated'];
const HEAD_LENGTH = 10;
const TAIL_LENGTH = 10;
const COLOR = 'yellow';

function main() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => !EXCLUDED_SHEETS.includes(sh.getName()));
  sheets.forEach(sh => colorize_cells(sh, 'C'));
  sheets.forEach(sh => colorize_cells(sh, 'D'));
}

function colorize_cells(sheet, column) {
  const range = sheet.getRange(column + '1:' + column + sheet.getLastRow());
  range.setBackground(undefined);
  const backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  const rows = get_rows_to_colorize(range.getValues().flat());
  rows.forEach(row => backgrounds[row][0] = COLOR);
  range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}

function get_rows_to_colorize(arr) {
  const obj = {};

  // make the object {'head1/tail1':[row indexes], 'head2/tail2':[row indexes], ...}
  arr.forEach((elem, i) => {
    let el = elem.toString();
    let head = el.slice(0, HEAD_LENGTH);
    let tail = el.slice(el.length - TAIL_LENGTH);
    if (head.length == HEAD_LENGTH && tail.length == TAIL_LENGTH) {
      if (head) if (head in obj) obj[head].push(i); else obj[head] = [i];
      if (tail) if (tail in obj) obj[tail].push(i); else obj[tail] = [i];
    }
  });

  // remove from the object the 'heads' and 'tales' that have only one row
  for (let key in obj) {

    // remove duplicates from the array [1,1,2] --> [1,2]
    obj[key] = [...new Set(obj[key])];

    // remove the keys which value is an array that has just one element
    // {head1:[1,2],head2:[3]} --> {head1:[1,2]}
    if (obj[key].length == 1) delete obj[key];
  }

  // return row indexes
  return Object.values(obj).flat(); 
}
```

It colorizes cells on all the sheets (except excluded) within columns ('C' and 'D' in this case) if 'heads' or 'tails' of the cell values aren't unique within the column.

You have to re-run the main function every time you change values to get correct highlights.

Comment: In speaking with Iamblichus I wouldn't need to do it using conditional formatting.  However @Yuri Khristich I will try your suggestion and let you know if it works for me.  Thank you Yuri for being the helper here and assisting.

Comment: Hi @Yuri Khristich, where do I put the names of excluded sheets?  How does the code know what to exclude?  Also what does this part actually mean and do ... (// remove from the object the 'heads' and 'tales' that have only one row
  for (let key in obj) {
    obj[key] = [...new Set(obj[key])]; // remove duplicates
    if (obj[key].length == 1) delete obj[key];)?

Comment: Also @Yuri Khristich is it searching the entire workbook for duplicates or is it searching the specific Column for a Duplicate in the Same Column.  As this is what I wish for it to do.  For example, look at Column C and if it finds a duplicate in Column C throughout the workbook (excluding the excluding sheets) it highlights them in yellow.

Comment: 1. You can exclude sheets if you add their names in the first line this way: `const EXCLUDED_SHEETS = ['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];` It works exactly the way as it was in your code. 2. If the cell is unique ('head' or 'tail' in the object has only one element: 'head1':[5]) this cell ([5]) should not be colorized, so this pair 'key:value' should be removed from the object. 3. If the key ('heads' or 'tail) has several identical values ('head1':[1,2,1,2,3]) it will remove the duplicated ones ('head1':[1,2,3]), I've done it by converting the array into a Set and then back into an Array.

Comment: As for the last comment, I don't understand is it a question? (Then my answer: Yes, it supposed to work about this way, you can test it and see)